# Remove leading zero with date formatter

Tags: objective-c, date, padding, nsdateformatter, leading-zero

If 24hr format, if date has no minutes, there shouldn't be any zeros padding.

example `where time == 3:00pm`:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"H:m"
```

result: 15:0

expected: 15

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in support to get something like `15:30` for 3:30pm and just `15` for 3:00pm. That would be pretty non-standard.

If you really want such behavior, use `H:mm` for your format. Then remove any trailing `:00` from the result.

Answer (score 0):

The DateComponentsFormatter has a property zeroFormattingBehavior to achieve this sort of thing.

> When the value for a particular unit is 0, the zero formatting
>   behavior determines whether that value is retained or omitted from any
>   resulting strings. For example, when the formatting behavior is
>   dropTrailing, the value of one hour, ten minutes, and zero seconds
>   would omit the mention of seconds.